# "both (of the) versions are correct"

Tags: prepositions, premodifiers

> - Both of the versions are correct.
> - Both versions are correct.

Are both of these correct? If only one, is it the latter?

Comment: Both of those versions are correct.  ;)

Comment: Sometimes you will want to emphasizen the correctness of *both* of the versions. But, generally, I agree with @DigitalChris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is not a static language with a singular authoritative definition. Both (of the) versions seem correct. The explanation is likely a combination of common usage, [elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), [dialect](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialect) and [idiom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom).